# GetModuleFileNameExA returns an incorrect value

Tags: java, winapi, jna

There is my code (**360** is my process id):

```
        HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010,
                false, 360);
        if (process != null) {
            int len = psapi.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, null, path,
                    1024);
            if (len > 0) {
                System.out.println(new String(path, 0, len));
            } else {
                System.out.println("GetModuleFileNameW failed");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(kernel32.GetLastError());
        }
```

**path** returns "`?`". What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How is `path` declared? Did you make sure `OpenProcess()` is not returning NULL? Did you try using `GetModuleFileNameExW()` instead? `GetModuleFileNameExA()` is Ansi, but Java is Unicode.

Comment: I changed `GetModuleFileNameExA()` on `GetModuleFileNameExW()` and now `path` returns `[B@774cdfcf`. Path is declared as `byte path[] = new byte[1024];`. Is it right?

Comment: You perform no error checking.

Comment: Yes, there is no errors, but how can I get the path of the process?

Comment: No. You perform no error checking. You don't know whether or not there are errors.

Comment: Use `char` instead of `byte`. `GetModuleFileNameExW()` expects a Unicode buffer to write to, and Java characters are Unicode. Also, `GetModuleFileNameExW()` returns how many characters were actually written to the buffer. Use that to resize your buffer before passing it to `println()`

Comment: You need to call [`Native.toString(byte[])`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#toString(byte[])) on the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
char path[] = new char[1024];    
HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010, false, 396);
if (process != 0)
{
    int len = psapi.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, null, path, 1024);
    if (len > 0)    
        System.out.println(new String(path, 0, len));
    else
        System.out.println("GetModuleFileNameW failed");
}
else
    System.out.println("OpenProcess failed");
```

Comment: Whether you obtain a `byte[]` or `char[]`, you need to call [`Native.toString()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#toString(byte[])) to properly convert to a Java `String`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I changed `if (process != 0)` to `if (process != null)`, cause _Incompatible operand types WinNT.HANDLE and int_. But I got an error **OpenProcess failed**. How can I find out the reason?

Comment: Call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx), and make sure that the process ID you are passing in is accurate and valid. Do not hard code it, as process IDs are not static values. Which process are you trying to query exactly? Your own process, or someone else's?

Comment: The post is updated. **360** is ID of process shown at [screenshot](http://s16.postimg.org/fvigpp2ud/taskmanager.png). `GetLastError()` returns "`5`"

Comment: **UPD:** I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this error code: **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: You will only be able to access processes owned by the JNA process's owner, unless you run the JNA process as administrator, or otherwise elevate its access privileges.